# Why do I get an error "using temporary as lvalue"

Tags: c++11

I cannot understand why I am getting an "using temporary as lvalue" error.

```
void setEdgeLengths(
    const Koala::AssocArray <
        koalaGraph::PEdge, 
        Koala::DijkstraHeap::EdgeLabs<int>
    > &edgeMap, 
    const std::vector<koalaGraph::PEdge> &E) 
{
   int edgeLength = 1;
   for (const auto& e : E) {
      edgeMap[e].length = edgeLength;
   }
}
```

The variable `edgeLength` is not temporary.

Comment: Please reformat and indent your code for readability. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: but maybe `E` is a temporary. We can't tell since we lack a [mcve].

Comment: Please identify the precise line which causes the error (use a comment to do so).

Comment: do you know that you want modify `const ref vector E` right? even your `e` is const :)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation found [here](http://koala.os.niwa.gda.pl/api/classKoala_1_1AssocArray.html#adb1aaab9178641673c844647700b3bc9) (thanks to Google):

```
Elem Koala::AssocArray<Klucz, Elem, Container>::operator[](Klucz v) const
```

This returns a temporary value (the non-const overload returns a reference but inserts a new item if the key doesn't exist). Try using [`valPtr`](http://koala.os.niwa.gda.pl/api/classKoala_1_1AssocArray.html#a6e52085d9c789f828705aa43d1cd96c7) instead.

```cpp
edgeMap.valPtr(e)->length = edgeLength;
```

Comment: Ugh, what an annoying choice for `operator[]`... +1 though.